# How to check the number of arguments and method from a class has in runtime

Tags: python-3.x

Given the class

```
   class TestClassRequiredMethods:
        called = False

        def publish_db_flaws(self, x):
            self.called = True
```

I'd like to check if the class has a certain method and an expected amount of params.
I solved half of it, now I can check if the object has the attribute but I can't find a way to check how many params are expected in this method.

```
if not hasattr(publisher, 'publish_db_flaws'):
    raise TypeError('The publisher must contain a "publish_db_flaws()" method')
```

**Answer**

The accepted answer is working fine for Python 2, if you are working with version 3, you may use:

```
import inspect 

class Publisher:
    def publish_db_flaws(self, params_string:str, params_integer:int):
        pass


publisher = Publisher()
print(inspect.signature(publisher.publish_db_flaws))
print(inspect.getfullargspec(publisher.publish_db_flaws))
```

- inspect.signature will bring just the signature of the method.
- inspect.getfullargspec shows a very complete information about the params.

Comment: Use [`inspect.Signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object) to check the function's signature and check if it equals the one you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `hasattr` you can use `callable(publisher.publish_db_flaws)` to check if the attribute is really a callable function.

More detail is available using `inspect` module as hinted in the comment by ForceBru. `inspect.getfullargspec(publisher.publish_db_flaws)` gives you information about argument names, if the function uses varargs or keyword args and any defaults. 
Similar information is available via `inspect.signature`. This gives you a Signature object which has a `__eq__` method for easy comparison. Note, that this is the preferred method for Python3. `getfullargspec` is to be used if you need compatibility with the Python2 interface.

Comment: Nice! thanks I checked it, there is one remark, the getargspec is deprecated, so I'm using getfullargspec. It returns what is necessary.

Comment: @Rodrigo Farias Rezino Oops. Thanks for the hint. Seems I haven't looked at the doc for quite some time... Updating the answer.